# Ubuntu 13.10 won't connect to the Internet - BCM4312

Tags: wireless, internet, broadcom

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a netbook from a USB, replacing the Windows 7 that came with it, and now it doesn't connect to the internet (it did connect when it was running Windows).

It also doesn't recognize an Ethernet cord.

- 3.11.0-15-generic
- BCM4312 [14e4:4315]

Answer (score 1):

The Broadcom 14e4:4315 is quite unusual in that the solution changes from earlier Ubuntu versions to later. In Ubuntu 13.10, which you are using, the device uses the native b43 driver and firmware that needs to be downloaded separately. Please first try to undo any possibly failed previous attempts; open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If the terminal reports that it was not installed so not removed, that's fine, please continue. Get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your report.